# Синтаксис for...in

Tags: javascript

Читал учебник в интернете на одном ресурсе и заметил что:

`for (item in items)` не отличается от `for (var item in items)`

Код работает в обоих случаях без ошибок, так в чем соль? Есть ли разница в этих синтаксисах если да, то скажите в чем?

Comment: Разница в том, что без `var` `item` становится глобальной переменной.

Comment: @Igor ну не знаю...вызвал переменную `item` вне `for...in` и в обоих случаях там было значение отличное от `undefined`

Comment: Вы попробуйте в документе. в самом начале вашего скрипта написать 'use strict' и напишите тоже самое без `var`

Comment: @MaximPro область видимости декларированной `var` переменной в javascript - не блок, а функция. Смотрите пример в ответе.

Comment: @Igor забываю об этой особенности в js

Comment: а если использовать вместо `var` --> `let` То и блок и функция является областью видимости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любое присвоение не объявленной ранее переменной (не в strict) создает эту переменную как глобальную.

```js
function WithVar(items) {
  var prostoPermennaja1 = 123;
  for (var item1 in items) {
    //console.log(item1);
  }
}

function WithoutVar(items) {
  prostoPermennaja2 = 123;
  for (item2 in items) {
    //console.log(item2);
  }
}

var items = {a:1, b:2};

WithVar(items);
console.log(window.item1);
console.log(window.prostoPermennaja1);

WithoutVar(items);
console.log(window.item2);
console.log(window.prostoPermennaja2);
```

И ограничения с `use strict`, как указал @AliaksandrPitkevich.

Comment: если добавить строгий режим, то будет ошибка

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich кстати да без объявления var программа не захочет работать это что касается "use strict"

Comment: Хорошо, хотелось бы тогда кое-что уточнить! Если мы пишем в не строгом режиме, переменная у нас становится глобальной, ок. Но вопрос в том: как и где она объявляется (неужели это типа синтаксического сахара в старых версиях js, что при объявлении в таком цикле мы подразумеваем эту переменную глобальной)?

Comment: @MaximPro Я бы на называл это "синтаксическим сахаром". Не в цикле дело. Любое присвоение не объявленной ранее переменной (не в strict) создает эту переменную как глобальную.

Comment: @Igor даже так? Ого, не знал!
P.S Напишите пояснение к коду, мало ли кто будет читать. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

не объявлять переменную, где бы она не была - это ошибка, если опираться на новый стандарт при поддержке 'use strict'. Сейчас во всех нормальных компаниях так пишут код. Итого если использовать не объявленную через `var` переменную в "строгом режиме", то будет ошибка, т.е. при попытке выполнить код без `'use strict'`:

```js
let obj = {
'qwe': 1,
'asd': 2
}
for (i in obj) {
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

ошибки не будет, тоже самое при работе `'use strict'`:

```js
'use strict'
let obj = {
'qwe': 1,
'asd': 2
}
for (i in obj) {
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

Вывод, всегда объявляем переменные и не паримся)

Comment: Немного страдает подача текста к коду. При первом прочтении честно говоря запутался.

Comment: а кто будет i объявлять ?

Comment: А что вызвало проблему понимания кода?

Comment: @zb' так в том-то и суть, что если при объявлении `i` все понятно, что происходит, то без объявления происходит либо не происходит ошибка при определенных условиях. Поэтому я специально не объявлял тут `i` чтобы показать разницу

Comment: так и показали бы рабочий пример :) с объявлением `var` в начале и `let` в for. какой смысл в двух неправильных примерах. Там по хорошему надо рассказать, что var в цикле объявлять не надо, потому что это будет переобъявление итд